# Assigning Text Box Values to a String Array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to assign each of the values I enter into multiple text boxes into a string array in JavaScript?

### javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var ch[];

  function getAllValues() {
   alert('Entered');

   for(var i=0;i<5;i++) {
      ch.push(document.getElementsByName("src")[i]);
    };

 alert(ch);
}
</script>
```

### home.jsp

```
<form method="post" name="myform" onsubmit="getAllValues();">//
    <%
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    %>
    <input type="text" name="src"/ >
    <%
        }
    %>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>


var ch[];
```

Here there are 5 text boxes. I want to assign the values entered here into an array using JavaScript.

Does anybody have any idea how to do this? I was stuck on this for 2 days.

Comment: Maybe nobody understand your problem.

Comment: Are you actually saying that you want to attach events to these inputs that updates a array when the input is modified? also are you using any javascript libraries at the moment (e.g. jQuery) that might help with this task?

Comment: cant we do that in javascript?

Comment: Of course we can. gordatron is just asking for clarification because your question isn't clear.  You might provide us with some of the code you've already created so that we can help you out, rather than actually do it for you.

Comment: @gogo, thanks for the clarification.  I've provided a solution below.

Comment: i have updated the question with what exactly i am trying to do and I have succeeded in it with your help.. thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
  ch.push(document.getElementsByName("src")[i]);
}
```

### Edit

```
<% for(int i=0;i<5;i++) { %>      
  <input type="text" name="src" onBlur="srcBlur()" />
<% } %>
```

...

```
var src = new Array();

function srcBlur(this) {
  if(this == document.getElementsByName("src")[0]) src[0] = this.value;
  else if(this == document.getElementsByName("src")[1]) src[1] = this.value;
  else if(this == document.getElementsByName("src")[2]) src[2] = this.value;
  else if(this == document.getElementsByName("src")[3]) src[3] = this.value;

  if(src[0] && src[1] && src[2] && src[3] && src[4]) {
    for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
      ch.push(src[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i want to assign it one by one into the array.. that is,after entering some value into the first text box and move onto the second one,the first value should be stored into the array.. its not working even if i use onblur

Comment: Your first code helped me to accomplish my task.. I had to modify it a bit to the way i wanted. It helped me a lot.. thanks !!!

Answer (score 1):

```
 <script>
 var str = "";
 function getAllValues() {
     var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
     for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
         str += inputs[i].value + "  ";
     }
     alert(str);
 }
</script>
```

Comment: You obtain a string, not an array

Answer (score 1):

First, to save yourself a headache, you might consider giving your inputs unique names/ids, like this:

```
<% for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { %>
    <input type="text" name="src<%= i %>" id="src<%= i %>"/ >
<% } %>
```

Then your JavaScript would be something like this:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]'),
    inputLen = inputs.length,
    ch = [],
    i,
    updateVal = function () {
        var id = this.id.replace('src', '');
        ch[id] = inputs[id].value;
    };

for (i = 0; i < inputLen; i += 1) {
    ch[i] = inputs[i].value;
    inputs[i].onchange = updateVal;
}
```

And you can see in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/38jCm/) that it works.  It populates the `ch` array with the initial (blank) values of the inputs and then updates the values every time you change an input.

Comment: Thanks.. I was able to solve it with the same idea where i assigned unique id's to each input element.. I used onblur method in input element where I sent 'i' as parameter to javascript and used this code to accomplish my task..  ch.push(document.getElementsByName(<%=i%>.value)); where 'i' is the input element's name.

Comment: Why `onblur` instead of `onchange`?  `onblur` increases your overhead, as you only need to update the array when the values change.

Comment: `onchange` will only run the function if the value changes `onblur`, whereas `onblur` will run it every time.  That overhead is unnecessary.

Comment: BTW, if you found my answer at all helpful, I wouldn't object to an upvote.  ;)

Comment: vote up needs a minimum reputation.. as I am new to this forum,i dont have the minimum reputation to give your up vote. BTW Thanks for ur help *UP VOTE* ;)

Answer (score 0):

Give a class to your inputs, for example inp. Then you can write:

```
var result = $('.inp').map(function(m, i){ return i.value;})
```

result will be the array of values

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using jquery

```
var arr = new Array();
    $("input[name='src']").each(function () {
        arr.push($(this).val());
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var stringArr = [];

for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    var element = document.createElement("input");
    element.setAttribute("type", "text");
    element.setAttribute("name", "textbox_" + i);
    element.setAttribute("id", "textbox_" + i);
    element.onkeyup = function () {
        keyPressFunc(this.id)
    };
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    stringArr.push("");
}

function keyPressFunc(elem) {
    var index = elem.split("_")[1];
    stringArr[index] = document.getElementById(elem).value;
    alert(stringArr);
}
```